# What drivers work with mongodb for C# in a medium trust hosting environment?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have been using mongodb for a while now...been using the NoRM drivers pretty successfully.

Recently I learned that NoRM is pretty much dead in terms of development, so I went looking around. I found a few options, including the official 10gen driver, but the problem is that most of them seem to only work in a full trust environment.

This seems a bit short sided because most developers at least start in a shared environment while building their gizmos...

Anyway, my question is, what drivers are people using for their c# mongoDB apps?

Thanks,
David

Comment: I got a note from the 10gen team telling me that they have bumped up the priority of getting the official driver to work in a shared environment. It will be available in the next release which should, hopefully be available in the next 4 - 8 weeks. Here's hopin.

Comment: The only caveat I would add to that is that we still don't know what operations medium trust is blocking. It is possible that we require those operations and can't work around them, in which case the outcome might be that we either don't support the official C# driver in medium trust or that the support will require too much work to be finished in time for the next release.

Comment: The JIRA case for getting the official C# driver to run under medium trust is: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-348

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using the 10gen driver on AppHarbor w/ no problems. I also believe there's a few hosts that will run your code in full trust.